# Pasar el contenido de una ventana a una Tab en PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo el siguiente código de dos ventanas distintas, las cuales funcionan bien de manera individual.

Y quiero pasar el contenido de la ventana1  a cada una de las pestañas de la ventana principal, para separar la lógica de cada una de ellas.

Lastimosamente cada método que he intentado, me muestra el contenido de la 1ra importación y/o ventana1, mostrando solo el contenido de esta y ocultando las pestañas por completo.

¿Alguna sugerencia para poder tener el contenido de la ventana1 importada, dentro de cada una de las pestañas de la ventana principal?

PD: En los 2 modulos hice la correcta importación de PyQt5.QtCore, PyQt5.QtWidgets, sys, Qt. Los elimine del codigo de ejemplo, para no hacer la redacción tan larga.

**Ventana1**

```py
class Ventana(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("ST")

        ContenedorVertical = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel("Unir PDFs")
        ContenedorVertical.addWidget(label, 0)

        Formulario1 = QFormLayout()
        Formulario1.addRow("Unir PDFs", QPushButton("Unir"))
        Formulario1.addRow("Seleccionar carpeta", QLineEdit())
        ContenedorVertical.addLayout(Formulario1)

        CajaTexto = QTextEdit()
        ContenedorVertical.addWidget(CajaTexto)

        self.setLayout(ContenedorVertical)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Ventana()
screen.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Ventana principal**

```py
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label1 = QLabel("Example content contained in a tab.")
        label2 = QLabel("More example text in the second tab.")

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(label1, "Tab 1")
        tabwidget.addTab(label2, "Tab 2")
        layout.addWidget(tabwidget, 0, 0)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entiendo correctamente, prueba esto:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from ventana1 import Ventana


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

#        label1 = QLabel("Example content contained in a tab.")
#        label2 = QLabel("More example text in the second tab.")
        widget1 = Ventana()                                      # +++ 
        widget2 = Ventana()                                      # +++

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        
        tabwidget.addTab(widget1, "Tab 1")                       # + widget1
        tabwidget.addTab(widget2, "Tab 2")                       # + widget2
        layout.addWidget(tabwidget, 0, 0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ventana1.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ventana(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("ST")

        ContenedorVertical = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel("Unir PDFs")
        ContenedorVertical.addWidget(label, 0)

        Formulario1 = QFormLayout()
        Formulario1.addRow("Unir PDFs", QPushButton("Unir"))
        Formulario1.addRow("Seleccionar carpeta", QLineEdit())
        ContenedorVertical.addLayout(Formulario1)

        CajaTexto = QTextEdit()
        ContenedorVertical.addWidget(CajaTexto)

        self.setLayout(ContenedorVertical)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]     [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias. Aunque ahora noto que si ejecuto el modulo Ventana1.py por si solo, no se muesta el contenido de la ventana y se cierra solo, me imagino que es por las lineas que se eliminaron al final.

Comment: Acerca de mi comentario anterior, para que cada modulo se pueda ejecutar tambien de manera independiente, se agrega la instrucción `if __name__ == "__main__"` al final del codigo de ventana1.py luego se agregan las lineas que se eliminaron en la solución de **S. Nick**